# APNS: Receive non silent notifications if app is not running?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

As I can see in the APNS documentation, silent notifications are handled in `didreceiveremotenotification` if the app is not running, but they have an low priority. So sometimes my iOS application doesn't receive silent notifications.

Does iOS show non silent notifications, if the app is not running (not in foreground, not in background)? And will a non silent notification trigger the `didreceiveremotenotification`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non silent notifications,

`didreceiveremotenotification` will be triggered if the app is in `active` or `inactive` state. Not when `terminated` or `suspended` state.
In case of `terminated` or `suspended` state when user taps on notification app will be launched by calling  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `launchingOptions` will have the payload as `Dictionary`.

In case you provide `UNNotificationServiceExtension` then iOS will call `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` on receiving the notification and you can use it to customize the content of a remote notification before it is delivered to the user.
read:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

In case you provide `UNNotificationContentExtension` then iOS will call the `didReceive` on receiving the notification and you can use it custom load notification content.

Read : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension

**P.S:**

Normal notifications can not be used as an alternative/work around to silent notification just because you cant use silent notification in app terminated state.

Silent notifications are intended for syncing the client app with the updated content available at server. As this can be done without the explicit user interaction silent notification can be used.

Silent notifications must contain  `content-available` key and must not contain  alert, sound, or badge keys. 
read : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Where as in case of normal notification, there is no way to hide notification banner/alert/sound unless the user setting on phone says so.

Comment: Normal notifications will be always show up, also if the app is in suspended or terminated state?

Comment: Yes buddy :) App state will only modify how the notification is handed over to your app as I explained above. Notification will always show up based on the user's device setting for notification (like alert or banner) No way to stop it from being appeared to user programmatically